How to fix Error: Could not find com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3?
I haven't been able to find a fix for this error so far:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'spreadfoundation'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

    at makeError (C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Spread\spread-foundation\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Spread\spread-foundation\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Spread\spread-foundation\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Victor\Documents\Spread\spread-foundation\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

my android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 21
      compileSdkVersion = 34
      targetSdkVersion = 34
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

        buildscript {
            ext {
              buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
              minSdkVersion = 21
              compileSdkVersion = 34
              targetSdkVersion = 34
            }
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3'
                classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0")

                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                // in the individual module build.gradle files
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                mavenLocal()
                maven {
                    // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                    url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
                }
                maven {
                    // Android JSC is installed from npm
                    url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
                }

                google()
                jcenter()
                maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
            }
        }
        //implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:sthetho:2.0.0'
        //classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0")


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}


(I saw about JCenter closing and some ways to fix it, i read this: https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown,but it didn't work).
I looked in old questions but none of them helped, some from 2021 and one from 2023.
I made this application in 2020/21 and updated the API level, but I need to update again and I'm having problems with this module. The first correction I made was to add namespace = "..." in several modules because it was a slightly old application

In the repositories part remove the jcenter() and put jitpack jcenter is an almost deprecated repository that only contains old dependencies, it should look something like:
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 21
      compileSdkVersion = 34
      targetSdkVersion = 34
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        //jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

The error describes that this dependency is not possible to get in any of the repositories lying there

It still doesn't work, just more errors appear

I got the bug here, but apparently you have to modify the library directly in the node_modules https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur/issues/444 the bug may be more complex than changing the gradle of the app, it says they fixed it in version 4.0.0
